# Multiplicative function, $\mathbb{Z}[a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Could you tell me how to prove that this function is multiplicative?

$R = \mathbb{Z}[a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2}]$

$f: R \ni a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2} \rightarrow a^2 + ab + 5b^2 \in \mathbb{Z}$

Here's my attempt to solve it:

$f(1) = 1$

I multiply $(a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2})(c+d\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2})$ and write it as $ac-5bd + (ad+bd+cb)(\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2})$ and then I apply to it.

Then I multiply $(a^2 + ab + 5b^2)(c^2 + cd + 5d^2)$ and Wolphram says that the difference is 0.

I know this isn't a correct solution, because it's very time-consuming, and a bit naive.

Could you tell me how to solve it in a more elegant manner?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If 
$$z=a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2,$$
then what is $z\overline{z}$?

Comment: $a+b\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2} = a+b\frac{1+i \sqrt{19}}{2} = (a + \frac{b}{2}) + i \frac{b \sqrt{19}}{2}$, so $z\overline{z} = (a+\frac{b}{2})^2 + \frac{19b^2}{2}$. Is that right? I don't see how that helps prove that $f$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Expand that. And remember that $\overline{z_1z_2}=\overline{z_1}\overline{z_2}.$

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see that. From the fact that $\overline{z_1z_2}=\overline{z_1} \cdot \overline{z_2}$ we get that $(a-b\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2) (c-d\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}2) = ac-5bd - (ad+bd+cb)(\frac{1+\sqrt{-19}}{2})$. And $z \overline{z} = a^2+ab+\frac{39b^2}{4}$

Comment: Oh, you made an error in calculating $z\overline{z}$! What's the square of $(\sqrt{19}/2)$ again?

Comment: Sorry, stupid of me. It should be $a^2+ab+5b^2$ and it's exactly my function.

Comment: Good! Well done. Now do you see how you get multiplicativity?

Comment: So we know that $f(z) = z \overline{z}, \ f(z_1z_2)=(z_1z_2) \overline{(z_1z_2)}$ And we use commutativity and the fact you mentioned getting $f(z_1z_2) = z_1 \overline{z_1} z_2 \overline{z_2} = f(z_1)f(z_2)$ Is this what you meant?

Comment: Correct again! Well done!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help :)